# Unwrap on the same spot

Tags: uv

Is there a way to select multiple faces (in my case they all have the same size) and unwrap them on the same spot of the UV/Image ?

I select those faces
[image]

and they get unwraped next to each other on the UV/image panel
[image]

how to get them all on the same place like in this exemple (here I have manualy moved each plane on top of each other)
[image]

Comment: it looks like it doesn't exist, you can use the snap tool to make it easier, but if you have hundreds of the same UV...

Answer (score 2):

Found it, first select one face (of the pillar for exemple) then select -> select all by trait -> normal (now each pillar has one face selected) u -> reset[image]

the faces are unwrapped on all the size of the image:[image]

simply resize it (when reset the face got the ration of the uv/image, try to get the ratio of the face you have unwraped) and place it where you want:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I see you have an answer but I will throw another one in. There is an addon called Tex Tools https://renderhjs.net/textools/blender/

You will see that it will help with your issue. it is 2.79 but someone made a 2.8 version

https://github.com/SavMartin/TexTools-Blender/releases/download/TexTools_2.80/textools.zip

hope that helps